# Chain Rule Multivariable

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate $D^2(F\circ\varphi)_t$, where $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

$D(F\circ\varphi)(t)=(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot(DF)_t$. So,

$D(D(F\circ\varphi)(t))=D(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot(DF)_t+(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot D(DF)_t=D(DF\circ\varphi(t))\cdot(DF)_t+(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot D(DF)_t=(D^2F)_{\varphi(t)}\circ (DF)_{\varphi'(t)}\cdot (DF)_t+(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot (D^2F)_t$

Can someone explain what is wrong with this?

Comment: The first line is wrong, the inner map is $\varphi$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the $D(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot(DF)_t$ term?

Comment: no, $D(F\circ \varphi)(t)=DF_{\varphi(t)}\cdot \phi'(t)$

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Ok, with that $F$ changed to a $\varphi$, I have $D(F\circ\varphi)(t)=(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot(D\varphi)_t$. So,

$D(D(F\circ\varphi)(t))=D(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot(D\varphi)_t+(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot D(D\varphi)_t=D(DF\circ\varphi(t))\cdot(D\varphi)_t+(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot D(D\varphi)_t=(D^2F)_{\varphi(t)}\circ (D\varphi)_{t}\cdot (D\varphi)_t+(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\cdot (D^2\varphi)_t$

Comment: I'm a little confused about the $(D^2F)_{\varphi(t)}\circ (D\varphi)_{t}\cdot (D\varphi)_t$ term, because $(D^2F)_{\varphi(t)}$ is supposed to be a bilinear map, so it should eat two vectors/vector valued functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an informal development:
\begin{eqnarray}
D (f \circ \phi) (x+h) - D (f \circ \phi) (x) &\approx& Df(\phi(x+h)) D \phi(x+h)-Df(\phi(x)) D \phi(x) \\
&\approx& Df(\phi(x+h))(D \phi(x)+ D^2\phi(x) h)-Df(\phi(x)) D \phi(x) \\
&\approx& (Df(\phi(x)+D \phi(x) h))(D \phi(x)+ D^2\phi(x) h)-Df(\phi(x)) D \phi(x) \\
&\approx& (Df(\phi(x)) +D^2f(\phi(x)) D \phi(x)h ) \ (D \phi(x)+ D^2\phi(x)h)-Df(\phi(x)) D \phi(x) \\
&\approx& Df(\phi(x)) D^2\phi(x)h + D^2f(\phi(x) (D \phi(x)h ) D \phi(x)  + D^2f(\phi(x) ((D \phi(x)h ) (D^2\phi(x)h))\\
\end{eqnarray}
Hence we get
$D^2(f \circ \phi)(x)h = Df(\phi(x)) (D^2\phi(x)h) + D^2f(\phi(x) ) (D \phi(x)h ) D \phi(x)$.

Since $h \in \mathbb{R}$, we can write
$D^2(f \circ \phi)(x) = Df(\phi(x)) D^2\phi(x) + D^2f(\phi(x)) ( D \phi(x) )D \phi(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

qbert is right, the first line should read $$D(F \circ \varphi)(t) = (DF)_{\varphi (t)} + D\varphi(t) $$ and subsequently $$D(D(F\circ\varphi)(t)) = D((DF)_{\varphi(t)} + D\varphi(t)) = D((DF)_{\varphi(t)}) + D(D\varphi(t)) \\ = D((DF)_{\varphi(t)} + D\varphi(t))+ D(D\varphi(t)) \\ = (D^2F)_{\varphi(t)} + 2D^2\varphi(t).$$ I think this is a little wrong since I'm not very used to this notation, but the first line is really all that matters.